# TypeError: n.widget.extend is not a function on IIS (ASP.NET MVC)

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm trying to solve problem with no luck. I have following error in browser:

> TypeError: n.widget.extend is not a function

This error occurs ONLY when I publish my code to IIS, and when I ran localhost there is no error.
I read topic about possible duplicate of JQuery, but it didn't helped me,
because I didn't find any duplicates.
I have ASP.NET MVC4 application.
My BundleConfig:

```
       bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js",
                    "~/Scripts/jquery-ui-{version}.js"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive*",
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));


        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/modernizr").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/modernizr-*"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/bootstrapjs").Include(
                   "~/Scripts/bootstrap.js"));

        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
            "~/Content/custombuttonsandradios.css",
            "~/Content/site.css",
            "~/Content/styles.css"

            ));

        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/bootstrapcss").Include(
                    "~/Content/jquery-ui.css",
                    "~/Content/bootstrap-theme.css",
                    "~/Content/font-awesome.css",
                    "~/Content/bootstrap.css"));
```

My view have this code:

```
 @Styles.Render("~/Content/bootstrapcss")
@Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
<script type="text/javascript">
   $.widget.bridge('uibutton', $.ui.button);
   $.widget.bridge('uitooltip', $.ui.tooltip);
</script>
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")    
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrapjs")

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).uitooltip({
        items: ".input-validation-error",
        content: function () {
            return $("[data-valmsg-for='" + $(this).attr('id') +  "']").text();
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Which version of jquery ui was being bundled? Tooltip widget had been added since 1.9.0.

Comment: I have:
bootstrap-3.3.7
jquery-3.1.1
jquery-ui-1.12.1

Comment: seems to be clueless. I ran your code and it worked well

Comment: Problem happens when I publish to IIS, not on a localhost.

Comment: I ran your code on IIS as well :)

Comment: So what potentially problem could be? Keeping in mind that on localhost everything is ok and on IIS is not.

Comment: well, @Popeye, I would say that could be the old version or even missing needed JS files on your IIS website.